# Custom Collection Admin ui Grid

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, datasource

is it possible to use a collection with a filter for Admin Ui grid. I tried this https://webkul.com/blog/display-a-modified-collection-in-grid-using-ui_component-magento-2/ but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Read this dev docs article: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/admin-grid.html

Here they show the example to create a custom collection admin UI grid

Comment: @SiranjeeviKS i saw that but it seems like i could be easer is that the only way?

Comment: You can create the Admin grid using PHP codes but it's not a standard way and PHP grids are deprecated. For now, Is this the only standard way to create Admin UI grid.

Comment: Okay good to know